# Google BigQuery: Cannot read and write in different locations: source: us-east4, destination: US

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I created external table in google bigquery using the below query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `dez-de-404011.zoom.external_yellow_tripdata`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'PARQUET',
  uris = ['gs://dtc_data_lake_dez-de-404011/data/yellow/yellow_tripdata_2021-01.parquet',
'gs://dtc_data_lake_dez-de-404011/data/yellow/yellow_tripdata_2021-02.parquet']);
```

but when I try to query the external table `external_yellow_tripdata`.

```
SELECT * FROM `dez-de-404011.zoom.external_yellow_tripdata`
```

I get an error `Cannot read and write in different locations: source: us-east4, destination: US`

How to resolve this, could you please explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you have a dataset called "dez-de-404011" and a Cloud Storage bucket called "dtc_data_lake_dez-de-404011".  Check that they have IDENTICAL storage locations .... it feels like the dataset may be in "us-east4" but the bucket in "US".  They need to be identical.